# Ruby comparision is always returning true

Tags: ruby

I am analyzing the response code from an HTTP Request, and based on that response code, determining how I'm logging that information. The problem is that the data is always being logged as true. For instance, when I get an 500 response code, I want to document a failure. When I get a 200, I want a success. However, I'm always getting a success. Can someone please take a look at my code and either tell me what I'm doing wrong, or what I can do to fix it?

Here is the code giving me a problem:

```
if response.code == "200" or "201" or "202" or "203" or "204"
```

I have considered that I am passing in a string, and so when Ruby evaluates the condition, it returns true, but I tried adding: `.to_i(base=10)` with no success.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Who ever down voted my question, can you please tell me why.

Comment: It wasn't me, but I'm guessing it's because the code is quite long, so doesn't represent a minimally failing example (which would be just the single line of code the comments refer to).

Comment: There is just no pleasing some people...

Comment: There are people who are trying to help you, who aren't paid, who are busy, and who don't have time to wade through a lot of code and appreciate you taking the time to provide a question and sample code that demonstrates the problem simply. They're probably not pleased.

Comment: I understand the people who give answers here. I think it is silly that they would down vote for something like that. If I were to post one line, someone would say "We need more info...", no one is forcing anyone to be here giving answers. I really don't care, I don't live my life here, I just think it is silly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As already mentioned, its the if statement: `if response.code == "200" or "201" or "202" or "203" or "204"`

An elegant fix would be:

```
if ('200'..'204').include? response.code
```

Comment: yeah, me neither, this is great! Consider posting it as a protip to coderwall, as I'm sure others would benefit from this nugget as well :)

Comment: It's basically the same as using `'A'..'Z'`. Ruby treats it as a range and knows how to increment the strings. It's pretty smart: `('aa'..'ac').to_a
=> ["aa", "ab", "ac"]`, or `('a1'..'b1').to_a
=> ["a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "a6", "a7", "a8", "a9", "b0", "b1"]`

Answer (score 5):

The issue is with the use of `or`. See http://www.coshx.com/blog/2012/10/31/rubys-and-and-or-operators-explained for a more detailed explanation of the difference between `or` and `||`, but the issue here is even more basic. It's as if you wrote

```
if response.code == "200" or true
```

which will always evaluate to `true`. You need to change this to

```
if response.code == "200" or response.code == "201" or ...
```

Answer (score 4):

the error is this expression 
      `response.code == "200" or "201" or "202" or "203" or "204"`
if the response code is '200', it will return true

if the response code is '201', it will return '201'

if the response code is '500', it will also return '201'

if you want to match the response code start with 20, you can use regex or start_with? methods.

for example `response.code =~ /^20\d$/` or response.code.start_with?('20')

Answer (score 3):

When you want to test against multiple possible values you have several approaches, each with their advantages and disadvantages.

Testing against a range or list with `include?` is suitable when the lists are *small* and aren't necessarily known in advance. A better version employs a Hash in place of an Array since lookup times in a Hash is usually significantly faster for anything with more than ~10 entries. Remember arrays are scanned from start to match, which in the worst case means testing each and every element for equivalence.

The better approach for more fixed logic is `case`:

```
 case (response.code)
 when '200', '201', '202', '203', '204'
   # ...
 else
   # ...
 end
```

These are optimized and execute surprisingly quickly. They're also flexible enough to handle a variety of matching types. In your case, since you're spelling out the logic already, this is probably the closest analog that works.

Remember that `x == 'a' or 'b'` is equivalent to `(x == 'a') or 'b'` which will always evaluate to true since `'b'` is not `nil` or `false`.

Answer (score 1):

As said by others your condition returns '201' because that's a "true" value, non true values are only nil and false.

A way to do it could be

```
if ['200','201','202','203','204'].include? response.code
```